# uipicker view implementation on action sheet

Tags: iphone

I have implemented the UIPicker view concept on action sheet, it is working properly but one thing it is not displaying properly that is row index. There is no highlighted row in the picker view.[image]

I have uploaded the image. Please give me the solution for it.

Following is the code which I am using:

```
-(IBAction)clickformedtype:(id)sender
    {
        UIActionSheet *asheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Select medication type" delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Select", nil];
        [asheet showInView:[self.view superview]]; //note: in most cases this would be just self.view, but because I was doing this in a tabBar Application, I use the superview.
        [asheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 117, 320, 383)];
        [asheet release];
    }


    -(void)willPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet {

        medicationtypepicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 216)];
        medicationtypepicker.delegate = self;
        medicinetypearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ml",@"capsules",@"eyedrops", nil];

        //medicationtypepicker = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ml",@"capsules",@"eyedrops", nil];
        //medicationtypepicker.datePickerMode = ui;

        //Configure picker...
        // [medicationtypepicker setMinuteInterval:1];

        [medicationtypepicker setTag: kDatePickerTag];

        //Add picker to action sheet
        [actionSheet addSubview:medicationtypepicker];

        // [medicationtypepicker release];

        //Gets an array af all of the subviews of our actionSheet
        NSArray *subviews = [actionSheet subviews];

        [[subviews objectAtIndex:SelectButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 266, 280, 46)]; 
        [[subviews objectAtIndex:CancelButtonIndex] setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 317, 280, 46)];


    }


    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
    {
        return 1;
    }
    UIPickerView

    - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        return [medicinetypearray count];
    }

    - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
    {
        return [medicinetypearray objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
    {
        medicinetype.text=[medicinetypearray objectAtIndex:row];
        //medicationtypepicker.hidden = YES;

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set property `showsSelectionIndicator` to `YES`:

```
medicationtypepicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks dear..actually i forget to mention this property in the code. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 3):

UIPickerView has a property called "showsSelectionIndicator" - set this to YES also set autoresizingMask to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth as follows...

```
    mTimePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;          
    mTimePicker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```